# Wait, before iterating next loop in objective c (ios)

Tags: objective-c, wait, loops

I want to loop through an array of images, subsequently setting them as the new image of a uiimageview, but because it's a for loop it obviously does it so fast you cannot see a difference.

I would like to add a pause of about 0.2s to the loop before it goes on to the next iteration.

Is there a way to do this?

And more importantly is there an easier way to accomplish what I want to do with some kind of inbuilt framework? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to what you want but will work better-Use this method of NSTimer with repeats as YES

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

use some method changeImage like

```
-(void) changeImage:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    //code to get the image
    NSUInteger idx=[yourArrayOfImages indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:yourImageView.image];
    if(idx<[yourArrayOfImages count])
        yourImageView.image=[yourArrayOfImages objectAtIndex:++id];
    [yourImageView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Do not invalidate the timer. You could use any way to index like use an instance variable, pass it as userInfo.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a delay to your for loop won't make a difference, because redrawing won't happen until you return control to the main event loop.  Set up a timer to send you a message every so often to advance to the next image you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

More context would be useful, but it sounds like you should look into [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the logic is how the Timer to be call a function recursively in a delay, and once the iteration of the array is done , disable the timer

```
NSArray *arrayOfImages;

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

int i = 0
int count = [arrayOfImages count];
- (UIIMage *)timerFired:(NSTimer *)aTimer{

if (i == count)
{
    timer == nil;
    return nil;
}
i++;
return [arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:i];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use **UIImageView property** - `animationImages`.

```
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSArray *animationImages;
```

For example you have an `UIImageView* animationImageView` :

```
// pass NSArray of UIImage's in the order of desired appearance
animationImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"image5"], nil];

animationImageView.animationDuration = 1.5; // duration (seconds) of ONE animation cycle   
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 3; // number of repeats (cycles)
animationImageView startAnimating];
```

In case you want to start some other **action when animation finishes**, use `dispatch_after` :

```
dispatch_time_t animTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, animationImageView.animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after (popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
     // do your stuff
     [self animationDidFinish];
});
```